# Match function response when no match found

Tags: match

I have a Match function nested within an IF function.  If the Match is found within the range, the formula works.  If the match is not found, I get "N/A": the match is not found.  I would like to get a blank cell instead.

Here is a link to an example spreadsheet that illustrates my question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_yLiQK_-7ygxAkoIgtFJLvWM3d-IA_rf1qo0_O_klWQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what just the Match function returns? Is that 0 for no result or N/A?

You could if it returns 0 replace

```
if (match(..) >= 1, "1")
```

with

```
if (match(..) >= 1, "1", "")
```

Otherwise you should check the result of match against some logic function like is ISNA or ISNUMBER

Edit: apparently it had to be:

```
=iferror((then all your formula),"")
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to resolve the problem.  Match function alone returns N/A when criteria not met.  ISNA(cell with match only) returns TRUE when function not met.